# Search partial word in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm kind of new to Elasticsearch but I would like to search the partial in the word

For example if I search "helloworld" is it possible to type only "world"?

Right now it work perfectly for case "hello" the elasticsearch return the suggestion helloworld for me

**Here is the code:**

`{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1, 
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "autocomplete_filter": { 
                    "type":     "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 20
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "autocomplete": {
                    "type":      "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "autocomplete_filter" 
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
        "mappings": {
            "word": {
                "properties": {
                    "text": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete"
                    }
                }
           }
    }
}`

Can anyone give me any suggestion?

Comment: you should use ngram tokenizer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html i suggest also edge ngram tokenizer

Comment: using n-gram instead of edge-ngram would solve your query to support partial search.